# How to delete node from PrimeNg tree component on drop while filtering

Tags: angular, typescript, tree, drag-and-drop, primeng

Hi I have a problem dragging and dropping from a tree while filtering.
When I try to drag and drop while I'm not filtering, the item remove from the right tree, but when I'm filtering, it doesn't remove.

[This is a video showing the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ySfIeDvwBhU4_MVBuvIStRKOMF9WuRAJ/view)

```html
<p-tree [value]="data" [draggableNodes]="true" [droppableNodes]="true" [filter]="true" filterBy="label">
  <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
    <div>{{node['label']}}</div>
  </ng-template>
</p-tree>
<p-tree [value]="_target" [draggableNodes]="true" [droppableNodes]="true" [filter]="true" filterBy="label">
  <ng-template let-node pTemplate="default">
    <div>{{node['label']}}</div>
  </ng-template>
</p-tree>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score -1):

You need to add unique key to all items (nodes) in TreeNode array ('data' in your case). Without key, Tree component cannot trigger events on filtered tree's nodes.
In your case, it could be enough to just copy nodes' names to node.key field.

Official documentation at https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/tree somehow eludes this - they provide link to github (https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/7237#issue-409791407) without proper explanation.

Comment: Hi kithrax.
I have added key to my data but still not working.
[Please check this video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yP0Bu-cQJHKGwLEjRHZBU1XRWc3U8lN9)